# Styling text within a circle

Tags: angularjs, angular, css

I'm styling customer initials within a circle, but the font is not always properly centered - as in the case with `EW` in the  below image.

In this snippet, I'm displaying the customer initials using `border-radius` to give me the circle; and if a photo exists, I just overlay that photo (kind of a temp solution).

The font doesn't always allow me to properly center the initials within the circle, however.

```css
<i [ngStyle]="{'background-color': dataItem.backgroundColor}" 
 style= "display: inline-flex; 
   align-items: center;
   height: 25px; 
   width: 25px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: white; 
   border-style: solid; 
   border-width: 1px;" >


 <span style="margin: 5px 0 0 4px; color: #000;font: 12px Arial;">
  {{ dataItem.custInitials }}
 </span>
 <img src="{{ './assets/profiles/customers/' + dataItem.UID + '.jpg' }}"   
  onerror="this.style.display='none'; this.className='' "
  (error)="noImage=true"
  height="25" width="25" style="border-radius:30px; margin: -1px 0 0 -23px;" />
</i>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me, for starters, get all those inline styles out of there amigo...just because.

Second, get rid of your margins on your span and apply `justify-content` to your parent (since you're already using flex anyway).

Third, get that `img` tag out of there as an element for multiple reasons and incorporate it instead into your `[ngStyle]` declaration to apply it as `background-image` for a cleaner DOM, and better looking icons overall...

So like from my example move the `background-color` back and do;

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': dataItem.backgroundColor, 
            'background-image': 'url(./assets/profiles/customers/' + dataItem.UID + '.jpg)'}"
```

If it fails, it will just show the `background-color`

Proof of concept below, cheers;

```css
.profile-dot {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
}

.profile-dot span {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<i class="profile-dot" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVW9D.jpg)">
  <span>CW</span>
</i>
```

Comment: and if the custom photo does NOT exist ? Will I be able to simply display those initials and cleanly ignore the background-image ? thanks much.

Comment: @bob.mazzo yep, just added an `ngstyle` example, if there's no image, the color is next in line, and no additional img tag and additional clutter. :)

Comment: Oh and it's worth noting, only thing that should be in `ngStyle` are style attributes that you'll be changing. Any static attributes should be in a css class and not inline to begin with, or people like me will curse you when reviewing your stuff :D

Comment: I agree completely about the inline styling. We generally do have an scss file for each component, but when you're running fast you tend to take shortcuts. And I certainly don't want to be cursed out. :-) THANKS FOR THE HELP MATE.

Comment: @bob.mazzo No worries, if your question is answered mark it as such so folks looking don't think it hasn't been. Cheers

Comment: Brilliant, mate ! I got it working. Thanks a bunch...Now onto a nice css tutorial for me... :-)

Comment: quick question: if the image DOES exist, can I easily disable the rendering of the custom initials ? In other words, the UX team might want one or the other (i.e. not the initials on top of the image).

Comment: @bob.mazzo sure `<span *ngIf="!dataItem.UID">CW</span>` would be one of several possible ways.

Comment: the `UID` always exists in this scenario. I am already doing some preprocessing on the grid rows in order to calculate that `dataItem.backgroundColor`, so perhaps I could check for the existence of  `'./assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.UID + '.jpg' `in my component code and then set a flag on the rows (`imageFound`). Problem is I need access to the file system for that check...

Comment: If you'd care to ask in a separate question I can show you how to remedy that scenario also, this one's getting a bit big. Basically I would make it 3 elements. One container parent, one span for the text, and one `figure` element that sits over the text in the DOM. So if there is no image than there wouldn't be one and you could see the background-color and text behind where the image would be but isn't, and if there is one than it renders over top of the text and background-color, voila.

Comment: done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786331/css-styling-how-to-display-a-persons-initials-or-a-persons-image