# CSS styling - how to display a person's initials or a person's image

Tags: css, angular

Using this lovely html and css as a guide, I'm able to display my initials over my photo.

This is great, however, I would like to display only the initials in the event the image does not exist; if the image exist, no peron initials should be rendered.

In other words, the image should overlay the initials when that image exists (so as NOT to see the initials).

```css
.profile-dot {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
}

.profile-dot span {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<i class="profile-dot" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20P2.jpg)">
  <span>BM</span>
</i>
```

In reality, the actual initials are coming from an Angular expression such as:

```
  <span>{{ dataItem.personInitials }}</span>
```

I got a hint re: the use of `figure`, but I'm not quite there yet - i.e.

```html
<figure>
<i class="profile-dot">
 <img height="30" width="30" onerror="this.style.display='none'; this.className='' " src="{{ './assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.UID + '.jpg' }}"  >
 <figcaption>
  <span>{{ dataItem.patientInitials }}</span>
 </figcaption>
</i>
</figure>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need? Can you rephrase a question a bit.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've asked a question. Can you explain how the example shown differs from what you want to do?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I've retracted my close vote. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: So sorry. It was a quick follow up question to my original css question which someone was helping me with. I'm trying to clarify now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a class to the image when the `onerror` event happens and then use that class to show/hide the `span` with the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

You will also need to add a couple of lines to your css fil so that it hides the `span` by default and it makes it visible when the image contains that class

```css
.profile-dot img+span {
  display: none;/*Hide it by default*/
}

.profile-dot img.broken-link+span {
  display: block; /* only show when img has class broken-link*/
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <i class="profile-dot">
 <img height="30" width="30" onerror="this.style.display='none'; this.className='broken-link' " src="{{ './assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.UID + '.jpg' }}"  >
        <span>{{ dataItem.patientInitials }}</span>
</i>
</figure>
```

Comment: that was almost exactly my original solution, except for the nice broken-link idea. good one ! The modified solution was also a nice one, however the person initials were ALWAYS superimposed over the image. Nice looking as well if that's what you need, for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748732/styling-text-within-a-circle/52749048?noredirect=1#comment92483758_52749048

Comment: you weren't too far, just adding the class and the piece of css

Comment: congrats, and thanks for that tip. Works like a charm - except for those annoying dev console errors that show up when images are not found...can't do much about that I suppose. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the z-index property in css, you can set the `<span>` behind the background image. You can learn more about z-index [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). (You will also have to remove the background color in order to make this work.)

```css
.profile-dot {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
}

.profile-dot span {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<i class="profile-dot" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20P2.jpg);">
  <span style="z-index:-1;">BM</span>
</i>
```

Comment: The only issue with this method is that it will render behind the dot which has a `background-color` so the text would not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd do something like this.

Notice if there is a valid image, it displays. If the link is a dud, then the background color and text would display. Also displays the text while image is loading (nice touch for slower connections).

Have a great weekend!

```css
.profile-dot {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-dot figure {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
}

.profile-dot figcaption {  
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-dot">
  <figure style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20P2.jpg)"></figure>
  <figcaption>BM</figcaption>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="profile-dot">
  <figure style="background-image: url(BROKEN-LINK)"></figure>
  <figcaption>BM</figcaption>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular, you can one simple `if` check

```
<i class="profile-dot" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20P2.jpg)">
  <span *ngIf="!dataItem.imageSrc">{{dataItem.personInitials}}</span>
</i>
```

Demo in action is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3q4i6

Comment: would be great, but I don't have the image source info on dataItem. I am actually embedding this logic inside a Kendo UI grid-row-template, and at this point I am deriving that image path on the fly. It's a temp solution until we permanently store images somewhere...